# Find the index of elements classified in each bin of histogram

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, histogram

I want to create a histogram using one column of my data and then find what is the index of elements classified in each bin.

The sample table is as follows:

| name | n_7 | n_6 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 20 | 11 |
| b | 14 | 50 |
| c | 18 | 21 |
| d | 11 | 4 |

I want to make a histogram based on column `n_7` and then find which names are included in each bin of my histogram. For example, the first bin will include 280 elements of the `n_7` column and I want to know what is the name of those elements based on the name column.

The following code creates the histogram:

```py
counts, binEdges = np.histogram(df2.n_7,bins=6)
```

Comment: You may find [np.digitize](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.digitize.html) useful, but you need to supply bin edges. Check also the note in the documentation
> If values in `x` are beyond the bounds of bins, `0` or `len(bins)` is returned as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

That may help you:

```
# Calculate a 2D histogram of data in arrays 'x' and 'y' with 60 bins in each direction
hist, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins=60)

# Initialize an empty list to store indices of data points within each bin
indices_in_bins = []

# Loop through the x and y bin edges
for i in range(len(xedges)-1):
    for j in range(len(yedges)-1):
        
        # Create a boolean mask to identify data points within the current bin
        in_bin = ((xedges[i] <= x) & (x < xedges[i+1]) & 
                  (yedges[j] <= y) & (y < yedges[j+1]))
        
        # Find the indices of data points within the current bin
        indices = np.where(in_bin)[0] 
        
        # Append the indices to the 'indices_in_bins' list
        indices_in_bins.append(indices)
```